# What can I skip after Amida in Shacharit?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, zemanim, priorities, shacharis-morning-prayer

I have very little time for shacharit, because I have to go to work. The minyan in the city where I live is very late. So I try to daven everything before the Amida and the Amida itself with a Tzibur, but after it I would like to skip and to cath up in the afternoon at my lunch break.
The question is: What can I skip or, better, delay until later?

Comment: user4817, welcome to Mi Yodeya and thanks for bringing your question here. Please note that this site makes no guarantee of validity, and does not offer professional (particularly rabbinic) advice. Treat information from this site like it came from a crowd of your friends, and use it as a jumping-off point for [a discussion with your own rabbi](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9146). Might I suggest you also [change your username](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/edit/4817)? Unless, that is, you're attached to the number 4817.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a rabbi, and this site makes no guarantee of validity. That being said,

- Tachanun is connected to the Amidah (the Rambam in fact considers it
  an aspect of the Amidah, [Hil. Tefillah
  5:13](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/920167/jewish/Chapter-Five.htm)),
  so you should try to say it right afterwards.
- The kedusha verses of Uva Letziyon should preferably be recited with the congregation. I've heard that Aleinu is considered like asking permission to leave; according to this you should probably try to say it before leaving.
- On the other hand, the *shir shel yom* isn't necessarily part of Shacharis; on Tish'a Ba'av we push it off until Mincha. If you have to delay something, I'd suggest this.